# Github: Repository > Projects vs Organization/User > Projects

Tags: github, github-projects

My case is that I'm a member of an organization and I'm assigned to lead a project.

In my Github org, I created a Project corresponding to the project's name and my member initiated a Repository.

Inside the Repository is this:
[image: repo tabs]

I'm just a bit confused right now. How do you guys go about this? You have an Org>'Project' where you initially plan to organize your issues etc., and what do you do with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your organisation can have “projects” just like users, and any repository can also have “projects”. Your organisation project might list the TODOs for your organisation, but for your repository you might have a board to track issues/PRs etc specific to the repository.

Read more:

- [About Repository Projects](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-project-boards)
- [managing organisation projects](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-access-to-your-organizations-project-boards)

Comment: hmm, i guess the mental model would be that org/proj boards are more general org/repo/proj boards are more specific to the actual repo itself..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature has been hobbled in the "New" Projects.

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/52841